# Bind variable in PARALLEL() to provide hint for optimization of query execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to provide the hint for optimization of SQL query using PARALLEL(4). This will obviously work.

Is it possible to use a bind variable in the hint like PARALLEL(:v1) as shown in the image or any other method available to do that?

[image]

Comment: I suggest try it on a plsql block having a simple select.

Comment: No, you can’t use variables here, unless you build the query dynamically.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT  /*+ PARALLEL('||vl||') */...';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
...
vl integer := 4;
sql_stmt varchar2(200);
v_hint varchar2(100);

begin

v_hint := '/*+ PARALELL('||vl||') */'
sql_stmt := 'SELECT'||' '||V_HINT||' '||'* from employee'

...
```